# Check the passive port in Spring Integretion FTP

Tags: spring, ftp, spring-integration, ftp-client, passive-mode

https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/retrieving-files-from-ftp-server-using-spring-integration-5ccc4a972eaf

I'm implementing FTP behavior based on the above site.
In the above site, I've only added passive mode to the ftp settings.

```
@Bean
public DefaultFtpSessionFactory sf() {
    DefaultFtpSessionFactory sf = new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();

    sf.setHost(host);
    sf.setPort(port);
    sf.setUsername(username);
    sf.setPassword(password);
    sf.setClientMode(FTPClient.PASSIVE_LOCAL_DATA_CONNECTION_MODE);
    return sf;
}
```

And I want to check the passive port when communicating in practice.

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "ftpMGET")
@Bean
public FtpOutboundGateway getFiles() {
    DefaultFtpSessionFactory ftpSessionFactory = sf();
    FtpOutboundGateway gateway = new FtpOutboundGateway(ftpSessionFactory, "mget", "payload");
    gateway.setAutoCreateDirectory(true);
    gateway.setLocalDirectory(new File(downloadPath));
    gateway.setFileExistsMode(FileExistsMode.APPEND);
    gateway.setFilter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<>());
    gateway.setOutputChannelName("fileResults");
    gateway.setOption(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Option.RECURSIVE);

    System.out.println(ftpSessionFactory.getSession().getClientInstance().getPassivePort());
    return gateway;
}
```

At the end, I added a passivePort with System.out.println.

It keeps saying -1, but how do I check the passive port when downloading a file from a real server?!

Comment: I've answered your question (or did I?). But this looks bit like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/218578), as your check makes little sense to me. Maybe you should better explain us what is it that you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The `FTPClient.getPassivePort` cannot return any actual value, before you transfer anything. Each transfer uses a different (passive) port. Until you actually transfer anything, no passive port is involved.

As the [documentation of the `FTPClient.getPassivePort` method](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#getPassivePort()) says:

> This method only returns a valid value AFTER a data connection has been opened after a call to [`enterLocalPassiveMode()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#enterLocalPassiveMode()). This is because FTPClient sends a PASV command to the server only just before opening a data connection, and not when you call [`enterLocalPassiveMode()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#enterLocalPassiveMode()).